# How connect fromm locally and run make migrations in postgresql docker service?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am building django aplication and use docker to easy manage this. My docker file for  django is :

```
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=server.settings

COPY requirements/prod.txt requirements/prod.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/prod.txt
COPY . .

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8000
# RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations
# RUN python3 manage.py migrate

# Run the Django application
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and also docker-compose for postgres is:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: auralab-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: auralab
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

and it is my django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'auralab',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

problem is to add make migrations in django dockerfile doesnt works, need connect and define connection for this. Actual error is then i have to access databse it has error:

> ProgrammingError at /api/learning/syllabus/
>
> relation "learning_syllabus" does not exist LINE 1:
> ...abus"."results", "learning_syllabus"."hours" FROM "learning_...

```
                                                         ^
```

also have error then i add makemigrations and migrate in dockerfile :

> 0.574 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
> 0.574
> ------ failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3 manage.py migrate" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Comment: You can never connect to the database from the Dockerfile.  I might normally expect the migrations to be checked into the source tree with the rest of the application; you shouldn't need to generate Docker-specific migrations.

Answer (score 0):

i have added

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: auralab
```

to be my services at the same netwotk but, it still cannt see my db host

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known